# Error in creating classes using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using JAXB for the first time and trying to create class files using my xsd files but unfortunately getting errors.

This is my xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="DbOperation" type="DbOperation"/>

  <xs:complexType name="DbOperation">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ruleList" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Rule" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Rule">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Action" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="TableName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="conditionList" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Conditions" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element> 
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Conditions">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Condition" type="Condition" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Operator" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Condition" type="Condition" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType> 

  <xs:complexType name="Condition">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="fieldName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Operation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

And these are the errors I'm getting :
parsing a schema...

```
[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'Rule' to a(n) 'element declaration
' component.
  line 11 of file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/priyanka.jain/Desktop/JAXB/Rule
.xsd
[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'Conditions' to a(n) 'element decla
ration' component.
  line 25 of file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/priyanka.jain/Desktop/JAXB/Rule
.xsd
[ERROR] cos-nonambig: Condition and Condition (or elements from their substituti
on group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this
schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
  line 32 of file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/priyanka.jain/Desktop/JAXB/Rule
.xsd
```

Failed to parse a schema.

This is the sample xml for which I've created xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DbOperation>

      <Rule>
            <Action>Delete</Action>
            <TableName>
                  issue
            </TableName>
            <Conditions>
                  <Condition>
                        <fieldName>
                trader
                        </fieldName>
                        <Operation>
                >=
                        </Operation>
                        <Value>
                250
                        </Value>
                  </Condition>
                  <Operator>AND</Operator>

                  <Condition>
                        <fieldName>
                traderName
                        </fieldName>
                        <Operation>
                =
                        </Operation>
                        <Value>
                jk
                        </Value>
                  </Condition>
            </Conditions>
      </Rule>

</DbOperation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML editor to validate your schema first...

You are referencing a type as if it were an element

```
  <xs:element ref="Conditions" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Conditions">
    <xs:sequence> ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:element ref="Rule" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

The "REF" attribute indicates that the **element** and **not the type**.

Error can be corrected in two ways:

first:

```
<xs:complexType name="DbOperation">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ruleList" minOccurs="0">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="Rule" type="Rule" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

second:

```
<xs:complexType name="DbOperation">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ruleList" minOccurs="0">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element ref="Rule" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element> 
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="Rule" type="Rule"/>
```